# fixed timestep and fps in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

For a mobile game I'm making, I need to run the physical engine at 60 fps, and the graphical engine at various fps, according to performances of the device.

To achieve this goal, I've been using this code, but I wonder if there wasn't a more elegant solution, since this one is a bit clunky, and doesn't seem to work that well.

Here is the render function of my Launcher extends ApplicationAdapter. the batches and runningLaunchable are defined in the class, and should work as expected.

```
@Override
public void render () {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //------ Set openGL and clear the screen -----------
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    //------- Run @frameSkip frame of physical engine --------------
    for(int i = 0;i<frameSkip+1;i++) {
        runningLaunchable.frame();
    }

    //-------- And now draw everything, starting with the main batch, and then the UI ------------------
    Profiler.next("Launcher","frames");
    getBatch(MAIN_BATCH).totalRenderCalls = 0;
    Global.getCamera().update();
    getBatch(MAIN_BATCH).setProjectionMatrix(Global.getCamera().combined);
    setActiveBatch(MAIN_BATCH);
    getBatch(MAIN_BATCH).begin();

    runningLaunchable.render();

    getBatch(MAIN_BATCH).end();


    System.gc();

    //--------- Sleep enough time to make the physical engine go at 60 fps ---------------
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long renderTime = endTime - startTime;

    //if too fast
    if(renderTime<=16*(frameSkip+1)) {
        float delta = renderTime-16*(frameSkip+1);
        if(delta <= -16) { 
            consecutiveOKFrame++;
            if(consecutiveOKFrame>3) { //if it was fast enough for 3 frames, increase framerate
                if(frameSkip>0)frameSkip--;
                consecutiveOKFrame = 0;
            }
        }
        else consecutiveOKFrame = 0;

        try {//Sleep enough to achieve the wanted framerate
            if((16*(frameSkip+1) -renderTime) < 32) Thread.sleep( (16*(frameSkip+1) -renderTime));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {//if too slow, reduce framerate
        frameSkip++;
    }
}
```